# Fan blew up capacitor, replaced capacitor, now it won't turn

Tags: wiring, fans

I have a three wire fan, diagram looks like this:

[image]
Source: [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=capacitor%20wiring%20diagram%20fan%203%20wire&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwiEmKThmuDrAhULl54KHetoDaAQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=capacitor%20wiring%20diagram%20fan%203%20wire&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzIGCAAQCBAeMgYIABAIEB5Q-d8HWMLmB2Do6gdoAHAAeACAAU2IAZ0DkgEBNpgBAKABAaoBC2d3cy13aXotaW1nwAEB&sclient=img&ei=efVaX8T3LYuu-gTr0bWACg&bih=715&biw=1249&client=firefox-b-1-d&hl=en#imgrc=2IirJx37MJ5fyM)

Or this one:
[image]
Source: https://www.electricalonline4u.com/2016/09/replacing-motor-capacitor-ceiling-fan-capacitor.html

The capacitor swelled but was still somewhat functional so I replaced it, the fan would barely turn.

The problem is I replaced the switch (switch looks like the top diagram, with three pos tied together) and capacitor (except its a purple and yellow wire cap with a value of 1.5 and 2.5uf, now the fan won't turn. But it does get hot (like 110C hot). The hot wire reads 120V at the switch, I can't really measure the other points because of difficulty of reaching them with the meter probe.

I am thinking that the coils could be out... I get 70Ω across the main winding and 150Ω across the secondary of the motor.
What could be the problem?

Comment: you need the right kind of switch.

Comment: The capacitor "blowing up" rarely indicates a problem soluble by replacing the capacitor, since something caused it to "blow up." Cut your losses and buy a new fan, rather than continuing to throw parts and money at this one...after which you'll almost certainly be buying a new fan.

Comment: The fan was working somewhat, I did not indicate that the capacitor was functioning even though it had swelled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When fans get old, the lubrication on their bearings is usually gone. Most consumer grade fans have oilite bushings. These wick oil from a cotton or wool to the bushing; as they age, they use up the oil, pull more current, and may pop the cap. I have recovered many fans by using a light oil and saturating the media with oil. When starting the fan, if you give it a flick and it runs but then slows and stops, this may be your issue.

Comment: The fan does spin freely by hand, but a extra frictional fan does not explain why the fan would spin with a bad cap, but not with a new cap

Comment: Did you get the same type of cap? Do you have a way to measure the cap? I have received bad caps that were brand new in the past.